# Need to clarify certain doubts regarding Testing Hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, neyman-pearson-lemma

I have some doubts in Hypothesis Testing which I would want to clarify.

We know, by Neyman Pearson Lemma that the test which rejects $H_0$ when $\dfrac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}>\dfrac{k}{1}$ minimises the linear combination $k\alpha+\beta$ where $k>0$ is a constant chosen based on our level $\alpha$, and $\beta$ is Type-II error. Here $f_1(x)$ is the likelihood under $H_1$ and $f_0(x)$ is the likelihood under $H_0$.

My question is, what is meant by "minimises"? Does it mean that the quantity, $k\alpha+\beta$ is FIXED AT A MINIMUM, by this test, no matter what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ I choose?

That is, suppose I had a level $\alpha$ from which I got $k$ and thus I know that by Neyman-Pearson Lemma, $k\alpha+\beta$ is minimised where $\beta$ is my Type II error. But now if I change my $\alpha$ to say $\alpha^{*}$, will the same $k$ work and minimise $k\alpha^{*}+\beta^{*}$, where $\beta^{*}$ is my new Type II error?

Comment: As you say, you get $k$ from $\alpha$ because $\alpha = \Pr(\text{reject }H_0 \mid H_0) = \Pr(f_1(X)/f_0(X)>k\mid H_0)$. I didn't know this lemma, it looks a bit strange at first glance.

Comment: Our professor has surprisingly avoided this lemma in his lectures. I am a first year undergrad in Statistics and when I asked him whether he would teach this lemma, he said we need a stronger background for understanding the Neyman Pearson lemma and that he did not feel it right to teach it to first year undergrads. The lemma seems simple at first sight, but when you think about it, it is not so trivial suddenly.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the statement of this lemma. There's like a snake biting its own tail.